# Convert cell of strings into column of table in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, variable-types

I try to use a vector as a column in a table (in MATLAB). However, I always get different errors. Below is a reproducible example, together with the recieved errors:

```
% What I have:
my_table = array2table(NaN(5, 3));
my_table.Properties.VariableNames = {'col_1' 'col_2' 'col_3'};
my_cell = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};

% What I tried:
my_table.col_3 = my_cell; %Error: To assign to or create a variable in a table, the number of rows must match the height of the table.
my_table.col_3(1:5) = my_cell; %Error: Conversion to double from cell is not possible.
my_table.col_3.Properties.VariableTypes = {'string'}; %Error: Unable to perform assignment because dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.
```

How can I solve this task?

Comment: The problem you are having is that you are creating the table as `double` type, and then trying to fill it with strings or other things. Can you not change the way you create the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the `cell` type you could use:

```
my_table.col_3 = my_cell.'
```

Advantage: You can store more than one character in each row.

Why `my_table.col_3 = my_cell` doesn't work:

```
%size(my_table.col_3) = 5x1
%                       ↕ ↕
%size(my_cell)        = 1x5
```

As you can see above, the size of the first dimension of your cell array does not match with the size of the first dimension of you table. So you can simply permute the dimension of your cell with `.'`

So now:

```
%size(my_table.col_3) = 5x1
%                       ↕ ↕
%size(my_cell.')      = 5x1
```

And matlab (and you) is/are happy.

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
my_table.col_3 = my_cell';
% or maybe you prefer
my_table.col_3 = cell2mat(my_cell)';
```

Let's analyze your problems:

1. Your sizes are wrong, you just need to transpose the input, from a row to a column!
2. As it says, you can not directly convert from cell to something else implicitly. `cell2mat` is a way of doing it.
3. There is no such thing as `my_table.col_3.Properties` so MATLAB gets confused and thinks you are doing something else with that dot `.`.